# Proofs of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin(x)=1$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, gamma-function, big-list

Well it's a little question:

How do you prove that:

> > $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin(x)=1$$

Where we speak about [the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

The most quick proof uses the reflection Euler formula because:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)\sin(x)=1$$

Well I think there are a lot of proofs so I add the tag "big-list".

Particularly I would be happy to see a proof using the squeeze theorem.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: $\Gamma(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right)
   x+O\left(x^2\right)$ is a way

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ is standard, while $\lim_{x\to0}x\Gamma(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\Gamma(x+1)=\Gamma(1)=1$. Multiply them.

Comment: Well it's nice thanks Angina seng   and Claude !!

Answer (score 4):

For latter part $$\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin x=\lim_{x\to 0} \Gamma(x)\left[x\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\right]=\lim_{x\to 0} x\Gamma(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x+1)=\Gamma(1)=1$$
By definition  of functional equation of Gamma function $x\Gamma (x)=\Gamma(1+x)$.

Or by [reflection formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20gamma%20function,For%20any%20positive%20integer)

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin x =\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi x}\cdot \Gamma(1-x)} \right]\cdot \sin x =\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{\pi x}{x\sin(\pi x)\Gamma(1)}\right]\cdot \sin x= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x\Gamma(1)} =1$$

Answer (score 3):

The [Legendre Duplication Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem)
$$\Gamma(z) \; \Gamma\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2^{1-2z} \; \sqrt{\pi} \; \Gamma(2z),\quad  \text{Re } z > 0,$$

and

$$\Gamma(z + 1) = z\,\Gamma(z),\quad  \text{Re } z > 0,$$

gives

$$\Gamma(x)\sin(x)=\frac{2^{1-2x} \; \sqrt{\pi} \; \Gamma(2x)\sin(x)}{\Gamma\left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2^{1-2x} \; \sqrt{\pi} \; \Gamma\left(2x+1\right)\sin(x)}{\Gamma\left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)2x}.$$

Then, taking the limit as $x\to 0$ with the well-known $$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!,\quad\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi},$$ forms

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\Gamma(x)\sin(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\,\sqrt{\pi}~\Gamma(1)\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}~2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$

Comment: Cool you make a bridge !!(+1)